# C# PayPal REST Api (.NET SDK)

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, sdk, express-checkout

I am using the .NET PayPal SDK (github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) and am able to successfully create a paypal request, redirect the user, the user completes payment and all is well.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to show the "Credit Card / No Paypal Account" screen instead of the "Login with paypal ... or click here if you don't have paypal to pay with credit card" screen.

Most of my users don't have paypal and just want to pay with a credit card (and I'd like to process it all through paypal, directly through their site so that users never give me their credit card number).

Here is the code I have that work for paying with paypal, but how can I tell it to show the "credit card/guest checkout" on paypal's landing page?

```
string PaypalRedirectURL(string returnURL, string cancelURL)
    {
        // create the transaction list
        var trans = new List<Transaction>();

        // make the actual transaction
        var t = new Transaction()
            {
                description = "Payment For Something",
                invoice_number = "inv1234",
                amount = new Amount()
                {
                    currency = "USD",
                    total = "2.00",
                    details = new Details
                    {
                        tax = "0",
                        shipping = "0",
                        subtotal = "2.00"
                    }
                }
            };

        t.item_list = new ItemList();
        t.item_list.items = new List<Item>();

        Item i = new Item();
        i.name = "Something I charge for";
        i.quantity = "1";
        i.sku = "item0001";
        i.currency = "USD";
        i.price = "2.00";

        // Add item to item list
        t.item_list.items.Add(i);

        //add transaction to transaction list
        trans.Add(t);

        // create the payment
        var payment = Payment.Create(GetAPIContext(), new Payment
        {
            intent = "sale",
            payer = new Payer
            {
                payment_method = "paypal"
            },
            transactions = trans,
            redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls
            {
                return_url = returnURL,
                cancel_url = cancelURL
            }
        });

        var links = payment.links.GetEnumerator();

        string paypalRedirectUrl = null;

        while (links.MoveNext())
        {
            Links lnk = links.Current;

            // get the payment redirect link
            if (lnk.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
            {
                //saving the payapalredirect URL to which user will be redirected for payment
                paypalRedirectUrl = lnk.href;
            }
        }
        return paypalRedirectUrl;

    }
```

I've tried numerous variations of [payment_method = "paypal"] (like (="credit_card", etc) but nothing seems to work. Again, I don't want to provide the credit card to this, I want the credit card "guest checkout" on paypal's site to show by default.

This is the screen the user gets on paypal (they can click the "pay with credit card" but I want to know if I can send them directly to the credit card screen without them having to click anything.

Current Page they are sent to:
[Default paypal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g72S2.jpg)

Page I'd like the user to see by default (with the credit card fields displayed):
[Desired default paypal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hgMl.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated .. thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using the PayPal adaptive payments API but I assume its the same for the REST API.  When a user is redirected to PayPal they should have the option to "Log in to your PayPal Account" and/or "Pay with a credit or debit card".  This option is presented on the landing page.  Validate the user doesn't already have the ability now... it might not be obvious if you've previously logged in to PayPal.

Comment: Yes it works that way currently but I'd like to show them the "pay with credit card" by default rather than "login to paypal" as the first screen

Comment: Can you share an image of what the user is seeing now?  It'd help to get us on the same page.

Comment: I've updated the post with images.

Current Page they are sent to: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g72S2.jpg)

Page I'd like the user to see by default (with the credit card fields displayed): [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3hgMl.jpg)

Comment: Not sure if that is possible.  An option to consider is opening a tech support question with them...  https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/